# Running a Windows process while controlling the mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows, process

I have a Windows program which has a GUI that runs on a PC.
In order to automate some of the GUI actions, I want to be able to move the mouse and type using the keyboard, but without interfering with the user's activity.

I know that I could simulate input events using SendMessage and PostMessage, but that requires the window to be in focus, and I want to eliminate this requirement.

My question is - is it possible to implement sort of a 'wrapper' that internally runs the original program, while patching its mouse and keyboard, providing it with a 'virtual' version of a mouse of keyboard?

I think of that as taking only the mouse and keyboard capabilities of a VM. Is something of that kind exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Likely, the only way to do this is with SendInput and activating focus of the window and child control you want to send keyboard events to.  Can you share your code of what's not working now?

Comment: I think I wasn't that clear. The thing is that the window must be active for the mouse actions to work, and I want to eliminate this.